# HP ComWare - Detecting mac/hardware address of CONNECTED interface

Tags: networking, hp, switch, hp-procurve

Alright, so I'm adding an IRF member to our switch stack.
They are 5130's, JG937A.

Only problem is the IRF cables are BURIED in the rack channel (I mean buried buried), and there's no way for me to look at the switches and tell which 10GBX interfaces are connected to which, thus I can't tell how the switches are stacked (daisy chain, ring, mesh etc).

So, wondering if I can do this by viewing the mac addresses of the interfaces, and seeing where they match up.

Question- is there a way to see the mac address of the CONNECTED SWITCH INTERFACE (on the other end of the cable)

For instance, I can view the mac of an interface by using

```
show current-configuration interface Ten-Gigabitethernet 4/0/49
```

I would then want to view the mac address of whatever interface is connected to 4/0/49 (probably 5/0/50).

Any other way to confirm this? To figure out how my switches are stacked, and which interfaces currently connect to which?

Comment: I should add that I did try viewing the mac address table, but I believe that only pertains to connected end-user devices, and does not include the interface hardware addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to figure out which switches are connected, and on what ports, by the output of the `display if toplogy` and `display irf configuration` commands.

```
[MDF5500-Core1]display irf topology
                           Topology Info
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
               IRF-Port1                IRF-Port2
 Switch    Link       neighbor      Link       neighbor    Belong To
 1         UP         2             UP         5           b8af-675c-6f93
 2         UP         3             UP         1           b8af-675c-6f93
 3         UP         4             UP         2           b8af-675c-6f93
 4         UP         5             UP         3           b8af-675c-6f93
 5         UP         1             UP         4           b8af-675c-6f93

[MDF5500-Core1]display irf configuration
 MemberID NewID    IRF-Port1                     IRF-Port2
  1       1        Ten-GigabitEthernet1/1/1      Ten-GigabitEthernet1/2/1
                   Ten-GigabitEthernet1/1/2      Ten-GigabitEthernet1/2/2
  2       2        Ten-GigabitEthernet2/1/1      Ten-GigabitEthernet2/2/1
                   Ten-GigabitEthernet2/1/2      Ten-GigabitEthernet2/2/2
  3       3        Ten-GigabitEthernet3/1/1      Ten-GigabitEthernet3/2/1
                   Ten-GigabitEthernet3/1/2      Ten-GigabitEthernet3/2/2
  4       4        Ten-GigabitEthernet4/1/1      Ten-GigabitEthernet4/2/1
                   Ten-GigabitEthernet4/1/2      Ten-GigabitEthernet4/2/2
  5       5        Ten-GigabitEthernet5/1/1      Ten-GigabitEthernet5/2/1
                   Ten-GigabitEthernet5/1/2      Ten-GigabitEthernet5/2/2
```